# Need help with grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to create 2 columns. One column will carry the users details..Avatar and user name..the other column will carry the users comments. Problem is that I dont know how to insert 2 controls into a gridview row..(Hyperlink with users name and avatar).
Here is what i have so far. I am not sure that it is right

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(cell);
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(ddl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the DataTable known nothing about the UI control you will use to show the data. in the aspx page you can configure the GridView to have templated columns then in the ItemTemplate definition you can put all controls you want and set their bindings using the appropriate aspx based syntax.

Comment: hmm.. cant i insert controls like with a table Tablerow.Cells.Add ....TableCells.Controls.Add.. Gridview inherits from table after all

Comment: System.Data.DataTable has nothing to do with GridView or HTML tables. It's a data container and not UI related.

Comment: I found this on the internet..see the updated code..It allows me to add controls to the cell..But I have two columns..how do i add controls to every row in every column